# Loading of Apache Avro plugin for Tranquility fails with Exception

Tags: avro, apache-kafka-connect, druid

For the Kafka Avro producer I run :

```
./kafka-avro-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic pageviews --property value.schema='{"type":"record","name":"mypageviews","fields":[{"name":"time","type":"string"},{"name":"url","type":"string"},{"name":"user","type":"string"},{"name":"latencyMs","type":"int"}]}'

{"time": "2018-05-31T14:23:11Z", "url": "/foo/bar", "user": "alice", "latencyMs": 32}
```

For Tranquility Kafka I run:

```
bin/tranquility kafka -configFile ../druid-0.12.1/conf-quickstart/tranquility/avro.json
```

Here is the parser part of the relevant `avro.json`:

```
"parser" : {
        "type" : "avro_stream",
        "avroBytesDecoder" : {
          "type" : "schema_inline",
          "schema"  : {
            "namespace": "SKY",
            "name": "mypageviews",
            "type": "record",
            "fields": [
              { "name": "time", "type": "string" },
              { "name": "url", "type": "string" },
              { "name": "user", "type": "string" },
              { "name": "latencyMs", "type": "int" }
            ]
          }
        },

        "parseSpec" : {

          "timestampSpec" : {
            "column" : "time",
            "format" : "auto"
          },
          "dimensionsSpec" : {
            "dimensions" : ["url", "user"],
            "dimensionExclusions" : [
              "timestamp",
              "value"
            ]
          },
          "format" : "avro"

        }
      }
```

Here is the error I get:

> ERROR c.m.tranquility.kafka.KafkaConsumer - Exception: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: io.druid.data.input.AvroStreamInputRowParser.parse(Ljava/lang/Object;)Lio/druid/data/input/InputRow;